# When I try to open my project in NetBeans it doesn't open

Tags: java, netbeans

[image]

The image is what opens when I try to open my project. It should be the code with the java icon. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you know how I can fiz it or do I have to start over?

Comment: i think the only chance is to create a new project and copie past your classes and libraries to this project, this is what i do when it happen to me, if there are a good solution i will be happy

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your project to netbeans.
Select file, and look for import project,
Chose eclipse project (if you made your project with eclipse) then browse to your project and press finish